# Meteor and Mongo DB delivers different results when doing findOne() on a Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have an collection with an array of objects in it (I just put some fields out of it, the schema is  working perfectly).

Collection Contacts:

```
title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title",
    max: 200
},
adresses: {
    type: [Object],  
    optional: true
     },
"adresses.$.id": {
    type: String,
    label: "ID"
},
"adresses.$.street": {
    type: String,
    label: "street",
    decimal: true,
    optional: true
}
```

When i do a :

```
 db.contacts.findOne({_id:  "59gXADmH9GLNDjELo"}, {adresses: {$elemMatch: 
   {id: "xpdYRKGGjHJLnCevM"}}});
```

on Mongo DB console, it returns:

```
{
  "_id" : "59gXADmH9GLNDjELo",
  "adresses" : [
    {
      "id" : "xpdYRKGGjHJLnCevM",
      "street" : "FakeStreet123"            
    }
  ]
}
```

Like I want it - just 1 element of the array back.

When I do the same on Meteor (Browser Console):

```
Contacts.findOne({_id:  "59gXADmH9GLNDjELo"}, {adresses: {$elemMatch:
  {id: "xpdYRKGGjHJLnCevM"}}});
```

I get all elements of the array back. How to solve this? I want the same result as I got in Mongo DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [**`._find()`**](http://underscorejs.org/#find) underscore method to retrieve just the document you want:

```
var doc = Contacts.findOne(
        {_id:  "59gXADmH9GLNDjELo"}, 
        {adresses: {
            $elemMatch: {id: "xpdYRKGGjHJLnCevM"}
        }
    }),
    address = _.find(doc.adresses, function(address) {
                  return address._id === "xpdYRKGGjHJLnCevM"
             });
```